# Prevent users from accessing admin area

Tags: mysql, php

Good Day,

am Facing a code error with my Admin control panel PHP page.

I want to prevent any other user from accessign this page unless his job_title= admin.

it works but even the admin himslef redirects back to login page again !!

here is the code

```
<?php
include('db.php');
?>
<?php
// Inialize session
@session_start();
ob_start();
// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) || ($_SESSION['job_title'] != "admin")) {
header('Location: index.php');
}
ob_flush();
?>
>?

<!-- STARTING HTML FORMAT !-->


?>
```

Any help ?

Comment: If you remove `@` before `@session_start();` is any error reported?

Comment: @mschr yes but they are alot :D

Comment: @PLB always reports " session start error function"

Comment: Are you sure that the values in $_SESSION are being set correctly on the login page? What is in there if you print them out at the top of your validation code?

Comment: @MinaWilson Session does not start, maybe it's already started. can you let me see reported error completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if still problems, let me know.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'dennis';
$_SESSION['job_title'] = 'admin';
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) || (!isset($_SESSION['job_title']) ? false: ($_SESSION['job_title'] !== 'admin'))) {
    echo 'Redirecting';
} else {
    echo 'You\'re good! Not redirecting!';
}
```

This may be an easier way to understand, just put into a function.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = 'dennis';
$_SESSION['job_title'] = 'admin';

if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) || !isBoss()) {
    echo 'Redirecting';
} else {
    echo 'You\'re good! Not redirecting!';
}

function isBoss() {
    if (isset($_SESSION['job_title']))
        if ($_SESSION['job_title'] === 'admin')
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['name']` is always defined and function `isBoss()` always returns true using this script. By the way, that function could be more readable and only one line: `return (isset($_SESSION['job_title'] && $_SESSION['job_title'] === 'admin') ? true : false;`

Comment: I broke it down so he could understand what is going on in the first example. isBoss() won't always be true because if the session['job_title'] is not defined or is not admin it will return false. I declared the session name and job title for my testing only.

Comment: Session is started, you define `$_SESSION['job_title'] before you call your function and session is never destroyed.

Comment: Please see my edited post. I stated they are only there for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a fubar newline :) Have added login page reference, which is unsetting the session variables you check for if logins fail.

Be **very** careful with where you put your `<?php ?>` tags - and in .inc files, such as db.php include - you may leave out the closing `?>` tag on last line to avoid accidental ENTER, then CTRL + S failures, sneaking in an unwanted newline char in your output buffer (ob). IF ob_start is activated, nothing is written from server before you choose or script ends. ELSE if its not, default is that every \n will flush output and start the Content part of the payload.

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start(); // put this on top-most line in your script
$ok = check($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);
if($ok) {
 $user = db_get_user_creds($_POST['user']);
 $_SESSION['name'] = $user['name'];
 $_SESSION['job_title'] = $user['job_title'];
} else {
 // session_unset();
 unset($_SESSION['name']);
 unset($_SESSION['job_title']);
}
?>
```

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // put this on top-most line in your script
// or, use ob_start at the very first line
// (with no widespace what so ever written out before it)

include('db.php');
?> I am writing out a newline here, session / header section is going to become unstable
<?php
// Inialize session
// @session_start(); moved up top
ob_start();
// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['name']) || ($_SESSION['job_title'] != "admin")) {
header('Location: index.php');
}
ob_flush();
?>
```

*See the 'I am writing out newline here' bit*

A little deeper down rabbithole goes; the communication flow is like this:

```
1) HEADERS such as
Connection: keep-alive\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n    (etc)
2) DOUBLE NEWLINE (one newline with no previous chars on that line)
\r\n
3) CONTENTS
Body
Of Page
```